# Why search engines use embedded style sheets rather than external style sheets in their homepage?

Tags: css, search-engine, html

As far as I know, cascading style sheets (CSS) can be applied to HTML documents in three manners:

- inline style (configure the `style` attribute of the target element)
- embedded style sheet (put css rules in the `style` element)
- external style sheet (link to a `.css` file)

**Inline style** is generally thought as an anti-pattern because the presentation and structure are bound too close to maintain. The **embedded style sheet** uses one or more `style` tags in the `<head>` section, which results in a better decoupling of presentation and the content. But the style sheets can only be used  in this HTML document. In contrast, **external style sheet** is usually considered a even better practice because the css rules can be reused in multiple HTML documents.

But I found all the search engines, such as [Google](http://google.com), [Bing](http://bing.com), [Yahoo](http://yahoo.com), use embedded style sheets rather than the external counterparts in their homepage. Why they don't just link to the .css file? What's their major concern? For performance or what? How can they cache the css rules in this way?

Comment: It's one less request that has to be made to a server, and with sites as large as the ones you noted, that makes a difference.

Comment: As others have stated it's one less connection, and connections have a flat cost plus the transmision cost. If your worried about best practices you shouldn't even be writing native css, you should use a css preprocessor https://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/04/12/ten-reasons-you-should-be-using-css-preprocessor and http://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, they do this because, to them, that extra 100 milliseconds it would take for your browser to load the separate CSS file is important. Additionally, this guarantees that the HTML will never load without the CSS also loading, so there is no risk that the user will ever see an unstyled page.

I'd imagine there could also be some performance benefit when you're dealing with an obscene amount of traffic, where it might be preferrable to handle as few requests as possible, even if it means you use a bit more bandwidth (this is more speculation on my part however).

Those sites all use server side scripting, which means they can easily make the CSS rules be consistent across all pages. For example, they could have a CSS file that they automatically inject into every page before they send it to your web browser. On their end, they still would only have one CSS file to maintain, even though on your end, it looks like they have separate CSS on every page.

All this said, this doesn't mean you shouldn't have your CSS loaded from a separate file; what makes sense for a company serving billions of pages every day might not make sense for your project.

Answer (score 0):

On my own website I use embedded minified stylesheet and here is why I made the switch.

1. The browser doesn't have to make an extra request to download my stylesheet
2. It is an application not simply a webpage, the styles are dynamically generated. This means on my development machine I still use regular external CSS.
3. The content of the page is gzip-ed which makes the final file size very small. Which also means very fast download.

You can still follow the best practices on your development machine. If you are building an application, you can have a build process that optimize it for the best performance possible.

Also it is nice to see your website  score 100% on Google Page Speed :)